# Update MongoDB field type from string to number with decimals

Tags: mongodb, database

I have data in the following format. All the fields are stored as strings. I need to get the `amount` field to Double format.

```
{
    "_id" : "soZkg8bvRfM6DHxgW", // string
    "itemId" : "1",              // string
    "amount" : "3113.40",        // string
    "type" : "Travel"            // string
}
```

I tried this operation, but after the update, the value of `amount` is 3113.00, not 3113.40

```
db.collection.find().forEach( function (x) {
  x.amount = parseInt(x.amount).toFixed(2); 
  db.collection.save(x);
});
```

So how can I convert from string to a number format that supports digits, and does not reset my current decimal values? Or should I use another format?

I need to be able to do aggregations with the amount data.

Answer (score 0):

Would say go for the bulk operations as they allow for the execution of bulk update operations which are simply abstractions on top of the server to make it easy to build bulk operations, thus streamlining your updates.

You get performance gains over large collections as the **[`bulk API`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite)** sends write operations in bulk, and even better, it gives you real feedback about what succeeded and what failed.

In the bulk update, use **[`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)** to parse the string value and return a floating point number. You will also need to filter the collection first to optimise the updates and send the update operations to the server in batches of say 500 which gives you a better performance as you are not sending every request to the server, just once in every 500 requests:

```
var cursor = db.collection.find({
        "amount": { 
            "$exists": true, 
            "$type": 2 
        }
    }),
    bulkUpdateOps = [];

cursor.forEach(function(doc){ 
    bulkUpdateOps.push({ 
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": { 
                "$set": { "amount": parseFloat(doc.amount) }
            }
        }
    });

    if (bulkUpdateOps.length === 500) {
        db.collection.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps);
        bulkUpdateOps = [];
    }
});         

if (bulkUpdateOps.length > 0) 
    db.collection.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps)
```